# When I set a custom view on an actionbar... why back button and logo dissapear?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm just setting like this:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_create_route);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ab_title);
```

if I set the logo and home enable after with:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

It moves the new layout to the right

Thanks

Comment: are you using sherlock??

Comment: support library, but It should be the same